# Dart / AngularDart - how to create diagram/flowchart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Could someone please point me to some tutorial or provide an example code snippet about how to create a diagram/flowchart in Dart? The simple scenario would be to have couple of elements connectable to each other and possibility to read which one is connected where. There are tons of JS examples but for learning purposes I would like to go the Dart way :)

Comment: It would be nice to explain the down-votes so I can either improve my question(s) or not ask at all. Wondering if it would not be a nice feature actually to offer a field for explanation when down-voting.

Comment: The problem is : This isn't a question. You're asking for a tutorial ; not an answer to a problem you faced.

Comment: Well, I somehow understand what you mean however as I am really a beginner in Dart and also Flutter I really do not know where to begin. I did not ask for a tutorial I asked for a pointer to a tutorial or small snippet where to begin.

Comment: I can understand as much. But Stackoverflow isn't for this kind of help. Here it's for questions that have one and only one solution.  You'll have a better success angulardart [gitter](https://gitter.im/dart-lang/angular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using a wrapper around an JS GraphViz library for a number of projects.

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pubviz - Here's the output: http://kevmoo.github.io/pubviz/

Also https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gviz

It's not super interactive or anything, but it's useful when you just want to visualize a graph structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice inspiration. Accepting the answer. Hopefully will find some time to send a more sophisticated question to some of lists in the future :)